# Using Provider package in flutter to listen to changes in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-table

In the job_details.dart file I want to listen to changes in the timestamp field when the start time or end time button is pressed and add the corresponding table row. But currently, I am getting value for my current job by listening to changes in my Jobs class and fetching the particular job using its ID. Therefore a new Table row does not get rendered when I tap on the Start time or End time button. How do I implement the above scenario to listen to changes in my Job class whenever a new timestamp is added to the _timestamps list and render a new Table row correspondingly?

**job.dart**

```
class Job with ChangeNotifier{
  final int jobID;
  final String name;
  final String startTime = DateTime.now().toString();
  String expectedDeliveryDate;
  final List<String> _progressImagesUrl = [];
  bool isCompleted = false;
  final List<Map<String, DateTime?>> _timestamps = [];

  Job({required this.jobID, required this.name, this.expectedDeliveryDate = ""});

  void editExpectedDeliveryDate(DateTime dt){
    expectedDeliveryDate = dt.toString();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  List<String> get progressImagesUrl{
    return [..._progressImagesUrl];
  }

  List<Map<String, DateTime?>> get timestamps{
    return [..._timestamps];
  }

  void addStartTime(){
    if(_timestamps.isNotEmpty && _timestamps.last["endTime"] == null){
      print("error");
      throw Exception("Provide end time first");
    }
    print("added start time");
    _timestamps.add({"startTime": DateTime.now(), "endTime": null});
    notifyListeners();
  }
  void addEndTime(){
    if(_timestamps.isEmpty || _timestamps.last["endTime"] != null){
      throw Exception("Provide start time first");
    }
    print("added end time");
    _timestamps.last["endTime"] = DateTime.now();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void addImage(String imageUrl){
    _progressImagesUrl.add(imageUrl);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void toggleIsCompleted(){
    isCompleted != isCompleted;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**jobs.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'job.dart';

class Jobs with ChangeNotifier{
  final List<Job> _items = [
    Job(
        jobID: 1,
        name: 'firstProduct',
        expectedDeliveryDate: DateTime.now().toString(),
    ),
    Job(
        jobID: 2,
        name: 'second product',
        expectedDeliveryDate: DateTime.now().toString(),
    ),
    Job(
        jobID: 3,
        name: 'third product',
        expectedDeliveryDate: DateTime.now().toString(),
    ),
    Job(
        jobID: 4,
        name: 'fourth product',
        expectedDeliveryDate: DateTime.now().toString(),
    ),
  ];

  List<Job> get items{
    return [..._items];
  }

  void addJob(String name, String endTime){
    Job newJob = Job(jobID: name.length, name: name, expectedDeliveryDate: endTime);
    _items.add(newJob);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Job findById(int id){
    return _items.firstWhere((element) => element.jobID == id);
  }

  List<Job> get completedJobs{
    return _items.where((element) => element.isCompleted).toList();
  }
}
```

**job_details.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:rupa_creation/provider/jobs.dart';

import '../provider/job.dart';

class JobDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const JobDetailsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const routeName = '/product-detail';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final jobId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as int;
    final loadedJob = Provider.of<Jobs>(
      context,
    ).findById(jobId);
    List<TableRow> createTimeStampTable(List<Map<String, DateTime?>> items) {
      List<TableRow> itemProperties = [];
      itemProperties.add(const TableRow(children: [
        TableCell(child: Text("Start Time")),
        TableCell(child: Text("End Time"))
      ]));
      for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        itemProperties.add(TableRow(children: [
          TableCell(child: Text("${items[i]["startTime"]?.hour}:${items[i]["startTime"]?.minute}")),
          TableCell(child: Text("${items[i]["endTime"]?.hour}:${items[i]["endTime"]?.minute}")),
        ]));
      }
      return itemProperties;
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(loadedJob.name),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      try {
                        loadedJob.addStartTime();
                        // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(JobDetailsScreen.routeName, arguments: jobId);
                      } on Exception catch (e) {
                        AlertDialog(
                          title: Text(e.toString()),
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();

                              },
                              child: Container(
                                color: Colors.green,
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                                child: const Text("okay"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text("Start")),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      try {
                        loadedJob.addEndTime();
                        // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(JobDetailsScreen.routeName, arguments: jobId);
                      } on Exception catch (e) {
                        print("here");
                        AlertDialog(
                          title: Text(e.toString()),
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                color: Colors.green,
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                                child: const Text("okay"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text("Stop")),
              ],
            ),
            Table(
              children: createTimeStampTable(loadedJob.timestamps),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**job_overview.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:rupa_creation/provider/job.dart';

import '../screens/job_details.dart';

class JobOverview extends StatelessWidget {
  const JobOverview({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final job = Provider.of<Job>(context);
    DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.parse(job.startTime);
    DateTime endDateTime = DateTime.parse(job.expectedDeliveryDate);
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        tileColor: Colors.black12,
          // contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
          title: Text(job.name, textScaleFactor:  1.2,),
          subtitle: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text("Start Date: ${DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(startDateTime)}"),
              Text("Expected Delivery Date: ${DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(endDateTime)}"),
            ],
          ),
        onTap: (){
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(JobDetailsScreen.routeName, arguments: job.jobID);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen your Job class with a `ChangeNotifierProvider.value`:

```
class JobDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const JobDetailsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const routeName = '/product-detail';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final jobId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as int;
    /// Here you search for your jobId but don't listen for changes of that class
    final loadedJob = Provider.of<Jobs>(
      context,
    ).findById(jobId);
    List<TableRow> createTimeStampTable(List<Map<String, DateTime?>> items) {
      List<TableRow> itemProperties = [];
      itemProperties.add(const TableRow(children: [
        TableCell(child: Text("Start Time")),
        TableCell(child: Text("End Time"))
      ]));
      for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        itemProperties.add(TableRow(children: [
          TableCell(child: Text("${items[i]["startTime"]?.hour}:${items[i]["startTime"]?.minute}")),
          TableCell(child: Text("${items[i]["endTime"]?.hour}:${items[i]["endTime"]?.minute}")),
        ]));
      }
      return itemProperties;
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(loadedJob.name),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      try {
                        loadedJob.addStartTime();
                        // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(JobDetailsScreen.routeName, arguments: jobId);
                      } on Exception catch (e) {
                        AlertDialog(
                          title: Text(e.toString()),
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();

                              },
                              child: Container(
                                color: Colors.green,
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                                child: const Text("okay"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text("Start")),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      try {
                        loadedJob.addEndTime();
                        // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(JobDetailsScreen.routeName, arguments: jobId);
                      } on Exception catch (e) {
                        print("here");
                        AlertDialog(
                          title: Text(e.toString()),
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                color: Colors.green,
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                                child: const Text("okay"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text("Stop")),
              ],
            ),
            /// With this you subscribe to changes of that job and listen in the builder
            ChangeNotifier<Job>.value(
              value: loadedJob,
              builder: (context, _) {
                final job = context.watch<Job>();
                return Table(
                  children: createTimeStampTable(job.timestamps),
                );
              }
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With your current implementation wrapping the table with a `ChangeNotifier` is enough to listen to it, if you need the buttons to listen too then you must move up the `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` in the widget tree before the body of the `Scaffold`

Comment: Still learning about the provider package. Thanks for the answer.